# How is Stack memory allocated when using 'push' or 'sub' x86 instructions?

Tags: linux, memory, memory-management, x86-64

I have been browsing for a while and I am trying to understand how memory is allocated to the stack when doing for example:

```
push rax
```

Or moving the stack pointer to allocate space for local variables of a subroutine:

```
sub rsp, X    ;Move stack pointer down by X bytes
```

What I understand is that the stack segment is anonymous in the virtual memory space,i.e., not file backed.

What I also understand is that the kernel will not actually map an anonymous virtual memory segment to physical memory until the program actually does something with that memory segment,i.e, write data. So, trying to read that segment before writing to it may cause an error.

In the first example the kernel will assign a frame page in physical memory if needed.
In the second example I assume that the kernel will not assign any physical memory to the stack segment until the program actually writes data to an address in the stack stack segment.

Am I on the right track here?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

yes, you're on the right track here, pretty much.  `sub rsp, X` is kind of like "lazy" allocation: the kernel only does anything after a `#PF` page fault exception from touching memory above the new RSP, not just modifying registers.  But you can still consider the memory "allocated", i.e. safe for use.

> So, trying to read that segment before writing to it may cause an error.

No, read won't cause an error.  Anonymous pages that have never been written are copy-on-write mapped to a/the physical zero page, whether they're in the BSS, stack, or `mmap(MAP_ANONYMOUS)`.

Fun fact: in micro-benchmarks, make sure you write each page of memory for input arrays, otherwise you're actually looping over the same physical 4k or 2M page of zeros repeatedly and will get L1D cache hits even though you still get TLB misses (and soft page faults)!  gcc will optimize malloc+memset(0) to `calloc`, but `std::vector` will actually write all the memory whether you want it to or not.  `memset` on global arrays is not optimized out, so that works.  (Or non-zero initialized arrays will be file-backed in the data segment.)

---

Note, I'm leaving out the difference between mapped vs. wired.  i.e. whether an access will trigger a soft/minor page fault to update the page tables, or whether it's just a TLB miss and the hardware page-table walk will find a mapping (to the zero page).

**But stack memory below RSP may not be mapped at all**, so touching it without moving RSP first can be an invalid page fault instead of a "minor" page fault to sort out copy-on-write.

---

Stack memory has an interesting twist: The stack size limit is something like 8MB (`ulimit -s`), but in Linux the initial stack for the first thread of a process is special.  For example, I set a breakpoint in `_start` in a hello-world (dynamically linked) executable, and looked at `/proc/<PID>/smaps` for it:

```
7ffffffde000-7ffffffff000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                          [stack]
Size:                132 kB
Rss:                   8 kB
Pss:                   8 kB
Shared_Clean:          0 kB
Shared_Dirty:          0 kB
Private_Clean:         0 kB
Private_Dirty:         8 kB
Referenced:            8 kB
Anonymous:             8 kB
...
```

Only 8kiB of stack has been referenced and is backed by physical pages.  That's expected, since the dynamic linker doesn't use a lot of stack.

**Only 132kiB of stack is even mapped into the process's virtual address space.**  But special magic stops `mmap(NULL, ...)` from randomly choosing pages within the 8MiB of virtual address space that the stack could grow into.

**Touching memory below the current stack mapping but within the stack limit** [causes the kernel to grow the stack mapping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46790666/how-is-stack-memory-allocated-when-using-push-or-sub-x86-instructions/46791370?noredirect=1#comment80542290_46791370) (in the page-fault handler).

(But [**only if `rsp` is adjusted first**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56718127/why-this-code-crashes-with-address-randomization-on); the [red-zone](/questions/tagged/red-zone) is only 128 bytes below `rsp`, so `ulimit -s unlimited` doesn't make touching memory 1GB below `rsp` grow the stack to there, [but it will if you decrement `rsp` to there and then touch memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46790666/how-is-stack-memory-allocated-when-using-push-or-sub-x86-instructions/46791370?noredirect=1#comment80551708_46791370).)

**This only applies to the initial/main thread's stack**.  `pthreads` just uses `mmap(MAP_ANONYMOUS|MAP_STACK)` to map an 8MiB chunk that can't grow.
(`MAP_STACK` is currently a no-op.)  So thread stacks can't grow after allocation (except manually with `MAP_FIXED` if there's space below them), and aren't affected by `ulimit -s unlimited`.

---

This magic preventing other things from choosing addresses in the stack-growth region doesn't exist for `mmap(MAP_GROWSDOWN)`, so [do *not* use it to allocate new thread stacks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1083172/how-to-mmap-the-stack-for-the-clone-system-call-on-linux/5369022#5369022).  (Otherwise you could end up with something using up the virtual address space below the new stack, leaving it unable to grow).  Just allocate the full 8MiB.  See also [Where are the stacks for the other threads located in a process virtual address space?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44858528/where-are-the-stacks-for-the-other-threads-located-in-a-process-virtual-address).

`MAP_GROWSDOWN` does have a grow-on-demand feature, [described in the `mmap(2)` man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap.2.html), but there's no growth limit (other than coming close to an existing mapping), so (according to the man page) it's based on a guard-page like Windows uses, not like the primary thread's stack.

Touching memory multiple pages below the bottom of a `MAP_GROWSDOWN` region might segfault (unlike with Linux's primary-thread stack).  Compilers targeting Linux don't generate stack "probes" to make sure each 4k page is touched in order after a big allocation (e.g. local array or alloca), so that's another reason `MAP_GROWSDOWN` isn't safe for stacks.

Compilers do emit stack probes on Windows.

(`MAP_GROWSDOWN` might not even work at all, see [@BeeOnRope's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46790666/how-is-stack-memory-allocated-when-using-push-or-sub-x86-instructions/46791370?noredirect=1#comment80551278_46791370).  It was never very safe to use for anything, because stack clash security vulnerabilities were possible if the mapping grows close to something else.  So just don't use `MAP_GROWSDOWN` for anything ever.  I'm leaving in the mention to describe the guard-page mechanism Windows uses, because it's interesting to know that Linux's primary-thread stack design isn't the only one possible.)

Comment: Linux doesn't use guard pages to grow the stack (and indeed didn't even have anything called "guard pages" related to the stack until relatively recently). There is no need for compilers to "probe" the stack so you can jump over map pages and touch a page near the "end" of the stack without a problem (all the intervening pages are mapped as well). Interestingly, Windows _does_ work as you describe: it has a single[0] guard page and touching that page, will trigger an expansion of the stack, and set up a new guard page.

Comment: On Windows then the compiler is responsible for that code which uses the stack never jumps over the guard page since such programs will crash rather than growing the stack. With local variables larger than 4K, this means a call to `__chkstk` is [inserted](https://godbolt.org/g/seb176) to do stack probing (or smarter) to ensure the stack is correctly allocated. Now, Linux does have something called "guard pages" between the max stack size and any adjacent VMAs, but that's just to reduce the chance that a large change in the stack pointer runs into an unrelated memory area (aka stack clash).

Comment: @BeeOnRope: Thanks.  MAP_GROWSDOWN documents a guard page, so I guess that makes it doubly unsafe for stacks: If that documentation is literally true, it will fault instead of growing if a thread stack ever skips a page.

Comment: Where are you seeing that doc? As far as I can tell from reading the kernel source `MAP_GROWSDOWN` simply considers the entire space between the current VMA range for the `GROWSDOWN` mapping and the closest lower-addressed mapping as "implicitly" part of the area that can be automatically allocated by that feature. So as long as you don't jump across (or into) an earlier mapping, it seems to me it would work (this also partly explains why they don't have a MAP_GROWSUP flag: that would leave the region between a lower UP and high DOWN mapping with ambiguous ownership).

Comment: Interesting, I see the [doc](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap.2.html) here, but my local `mmap` doesn't doesn't have it, simply saying: **MAP_GROWSDOWN** 
              _Used for stacks.  Indicates to the kernel virtual memory system that the mapping should extend downward in memory._

Comment: @BeeOnRope: Your copy might be slightly old.  Until recently the documentation seemed to suggest it was safe.  So do several SO answers (probably influenced by that).  Updated my answer, thanks for the info that Linux doesn't use guard pages at all for stacks.

Comment: It looks like perhaps it was added in man pages for [4.09](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/changelog.html#release_4.09). Even though I'm on 4.10, my man page version is stuck in 4.04.

Comment: Peter Cordes. I've looked into it more, and the answer seems to be "it's complex, but the documentation is probably wrong". On my box, allocating large amounts on the stack and jumping deep into it (i.e., a much lower address) skipping many pages works fine. That's consistent with my checks in the kernel source. On my box `MAP_GROWNDOWN` doesn't work at all: it always faults when accessing below the mapped region using [code like this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/79256/87246). This seems like maybe a [new bug](https://patchwork.kernel.org/patch/9802797/).

Comment: As far as I can tell, there were basically two flows through the kernel: the one that hits the guard page, which ends up in `__do_anonymous_page` and the flow when you skip over the guard page, which ends up [here in `__do_page_fault` for x86](https://patchwork.kernel.org/patch/9796395/). There you can see that the code handles the `MAP_GROWSDOWN` case with a check of `rsp`: so you can't at all use this as a general "grows down" area since the kernel is actually checking that `rsp` is "close to" this area, otherwise it will fault.

Comment: What seems to have changed lately is that the old "single" guard page was just kind of added onto the stack's VMA, but now that they moved to a 1MB guard to mitigate stack clash, they account for it totally differently (so it won't get charged to the process ulimits, among other things), which made all the flows now go through `__do_page_fault`, causing the regression linked above, or something like that. All that to say I don't see evidence for the behavior described by the man page: under the covers the guard page may be hit, but the behavior is supposed to be the same as the skip over case.

Comment: [Here's the change](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/?id=1be7107fbe18eed3e319a6c3e83c78254b693acb) to the stack guard page handling, which led to a bunch of follow-on issues, like [this one](http://seclists.org/oss-sec/2017/q2/562).

Comment: Finally, this also answers one question you had above: the region which is considered the "stack growth region" seems to be arbitrarily large, as long as `rsp` is adjusted first (which compilers do, of course). I was able to write 1 GB beyond the current allocated stack (with `ulimit -s unlimited`) and Linux was happy to grow the stack to 1 GB. This only works because the primary process stack lives at the top of the VM space with about 10 TB before it hits anything else: this won't work with `pthreads` threads which have a fixed stack size that doesn't use the `GROWDOWN` stuff at all.

Comment: @BeeOnRope: Thanks for all the research, linked to several of these comments from my answer.

Comment: "Compilers targeting Linux don't generate stack "probes" to make sure each 4k page is touched in order after a big allocation (e.g. local array or alloca), so that's another reason MAP_GROWSDOWN isn't safe for stacks" - I think there is something off here. Provided your kernel has the pre-stackclash fix for [CVE-2010-2240](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=CVE-2010-2240), there will be a guard page or guard gap. Unless your kernel got a screwed up version of the 2017 stackclash fixes (which increased the gap to 256 pages). Note pthread_attr_setguardsize() default is PAGE_SIZE :-).

Comment: @sourcejedi: that guard page isn't to trigger growth, it's to prevent anything *else* from allocating that page.  And to SIGBUS if anything tries to access it.  For thread stacks, the full threadstack mapping is done up-front, so no growth is needed (just lazy allocation of logical mappings vs. backed by physical page and wired into the HW page tables).  See [What is the actual size of stack red zone?](//stackoverflow.com/posts/comments/100386001) for a recent test that you can still grow the main stack arbitrarily by moving RSP very far and touching mem.

Comment: @PeterCordes my comment is not concerned with triggering growth specifically, only whether access beyond the stack will be detected, i.e. "safety".

Comment: @sourcejedi: Accessing unmapped pages below the red-zone will always fault.  You only need guard pages to make sure nothing *else* maps that memory below the bottom of the actual stack proper, creating a non-fault (stack clash). The reason Linux upped it to 256 guard pages is precisely *because* a huge overflow of a VLA could skip over a single guard page.  If Linux did require stack probes while growing the stack by more than 1 page, you wouldn't need more than 1 guard page for normal compiler-generated code. (I haven't read the details recently on these guard pages; I think that's right)

Answer (score 2):

Stack allocation uses same virtual memory mechanism which controls address access *pagefault*. I.e. if your current stack has `7ffd41ad2000-7ffd41af3000` as bounds:

```
myaut@panther:~> grep stack /proc/self/maps                                                     
7ffd41ad2000-7ffd41af3000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0      [stack]
```

Then if CPU will try to read/write data at address `7ffd41ad1fff` (1 byte before stack top boundary), it will generate a *pagefault* because OS didn't provide a corresponding chunk of allocated memory (*page*). So `push` or any other memory-accessing command with `%rsp` as address will trigger *pagefault*.

In the pagefault handler, kernel will check if stack can be grown and if so, it will allocate page backing faulty address (`7ffd41ad1000-7ffd41ad2000`) or trigger SIGSEGV if, say, stack ulimit is exceeded.