# Analyzing memory mapping of a process with pmap. [stack]

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, stack, mmap

I'm trying to understand how stack works in Linux. I read [AMD64 ABI](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/wiki/hjl-tools/x86-psABI/x86-64-psABI-1.0.pdf) sections about stack and process initialization and it is not clear how the stack should be mapped. Here is the relevant quote (3.4.1):

> **Stack State**
>
> This section describes the machine state that `exec` (BA_OS) creates for
>   new processes.

and

> It is unspecified whether the data and stack segments are initially
>   mapped with execute permissions or not. Applications which need to
>   execute code on the stack or data segments should take proper
>   precautions, e.g., by calling `mprotect()`.

So I can deduce from the quotes above that the stack is mapped (it is unspecified if `PROT_EXEC` is used to create the mapping). Also the mapping is created by `exec`.

The question is whether the "main thread"'s stack uses `MAP_GROWSDOWN | MAP_STACK` mapping or maybe even via `sbrk`?

Looking at `pmap -x <pid>` the stack is marked with `[stack]` as

```
00007ffc04c78000     132      12      12 rw---   [ stack ]
```

Creating a mapping as

```
mmap(NULL, 4096,
     PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE,
     MAP_ANONYMOUS | MAP_PRIVATE | MAP_STACK,
     -1, 0);
```

simply creates anonymous mapping as that is shown in `pmap -x <pid>` as

```
00007fb6e42fa000       4       0       0 rw---   [ anon ]
```

Comment: the function: `sbrk()` is for changing the data segment size.  It has nothing to do with the stack

Answer (score 6):

> I can deduce from the quotes above that the stack is mapped

That literally just means that memory is allocated.  i.e. that there is a logical mapping from those virtual addresses to physical pages.  We know this because you can use a `push` or `call` instruction in `_start` without making a system call from user-space to allocate a stack.

In fact the x86-64 System V ABI specifies that argc, argv, and envp are on the stack at process startup.

> The question is whether the "main thread"'s stack uses `MAP_GROWSDOWN | MAP_STACK` mapping or maybe even via `sbrk`?

The ELF binary loader sets the `_GROWSDOWN` flag for the main thread's stack, but not the `MAP_STACK` flag.  This is code *inside* the kernel, and it does not go through the regular `mmap` system call interface.

(**Nothing in user-space uses `mmap(MAP_GROWSDOWN)`** so normally the main thread stack is the only mapping that have the `VM_GROWSDOWN` flag inside the kernel.)

The internal name of the flag that is used for the virtual memory aree (VMA) of the stack is called `VM_GROWSDOWN`. In case you're interested, here are all the flags that are used for the main thread's stack: `VM_GROWSDOWN`, `VM_READ`, `VM_WRITE`, `VM_MAYREAD`, `VM_MAYWRITE`, and `VM_MAYEXEC`. In addition, if the ELF binary is specified to have an executable stack (e.g., by compiling with `gcc -z execstack`), the `VM_EXEC` flag is also used. Note that on architectures that support stacks that grow upwards, `VM_GROWSUP` is used instead of `VM_GROWSDOWN` if the kernel was compiled with `CONFIG_STACK_GROWSUP` defined. The line of code where these flags are specified in the Linux kernel can be found [here](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.4.184/source/fs/exec.c#L726).

`/proc/.../maps` and `pmap` don't use the `VM_GROWSDOWN` - they rely on address comparison instead. Therefore they may not be able to determine exactly the exact range of the virtual address space that the main thread's stack occupies (see an [example](https://rstforums.com/forum/topic/106625-centos-7-before-1708-piestack-corruption-vulnerability)). On the other hand, `/proc/.../smaps` looks for the `VM_GROWSDOWN` flag and marks each memory region that has this flag as `gd`.  (Although it seems to ignore `VM_GROWSUP`.)

All of these tools/files ignore the `MAP_STACK` flag. In fact, the whole Linux kernel ignores this flag (which is probably why the program loader doesn't set it.)  User-space only passes it for future-proofing in case the kernel *does* want to start treating thread-stack allocations specially.

---

`sbrk` makes no sense here; the stack isn't contiguous with the "break", and the `brk` heap grows upward *toward* the stack anyway.  Linux puts the stack very near the top of virtual address space.  So of course the primary stack couldn't be allocated with (the in-kernel equivalent of) `sbrk`.

---

**And no, nothing uses `MAP_GROWSDOWN`**, not even secondary thread stacks, because it can't in general be used safely.

The `mmap(2)` man page which says `MAP_GROWSDOWN` is "used for stacks" is laughably out of date and misleading.  See [How to mmap the stack for the clone() system call on linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1083172/how-to-mmap-the-stack-for-the-clone-system-call-on-linux).  As Ulrich Drepper [explained in 2008](https://lwn.net/Articles/294001/), code using `MAP_GROWSDOWN` is typically broken, and proposed removing the flag from Linux `mmap` and from glibc headers.  (This obviously didn't happen, but pthreads hasn't used it since well before then, if ever.)

---

`MAP_GROWSDOWN` sets the `VM_GROWSDOWN` flag for the mapping inside the kernel.  The main thread *also* uses that flag to enable the growth mechanism, so a thread stack may be able to grow the same way the main stack does: arbitrarily far (up to `ulimit -s`?) if the stack pointer is below the page fault location.  (Linux does not require "stack probes" to touch every page of a large multi-page stack array or `alloca`.)

(Thread stacks are fully allocated up front; only normal lazy allocation of physical pages to back that virtual allocation avoids wasting space for thread stacks.)

`MAP_GROWSDOWN` mapping can also grow the way the `mmap` man page describes: access to the "guard page" below the lowest mapped page will also trigger growth, even if that's below the bottom of the red zone.

**But the main thread's stack has magic you *don't* get with `mmap(MAP_GROWSDOWN)`.**  It reserves the growth space up to `ulimit -s` to prevent random choice of `mmap` address from creating a roadblock to stack growth.  That magic is only available to the in-kernel program-loader which maps the main thread's stack during `execve()`, making it safe from an `mmap(NULL, ...)` randomly blocking future stack growth.

`mmap(MAP_FIXED)` could still create a roadblock for the main stack, but if you use `MAP_FIXED` you're 100% responsible for not breaking anything.  ([Unlimited stack cannot grow beyond the initial 132KiB if MAP_FIXED involved?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56924725/unlimited-stack-cannot-grow-beyond-the-initial-132kib-if-map-fixed-involved)).  `MAP_FIXED` will replace existing mappings and reservations, but anything else will treat the main thread's stack-growth space as reserved;.  (I think that's true; worth trying with `MAP_FIXED_NOREPLACE` or just a non-NULL hint address)

See

- [How is Stack memory allocated when using 'push' or 'sub' x86 instructions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46790666/how-is-stack-memory-allocated-when-using-push-or-sub-x86-instructions)
- [Why does this code crash with address randomization on?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56718127/why-does-this-code-crash-with-address-randomization-on)

**`pthread_create` doesn't use `MAP_GROWSDOWN` for thread stacks, and neither should anyone else.  Generally do not use.**  Linux pthreads by default allocates the full size for a thread stack.  This costs virtual address space but (until it's actually touched) not physical pages.

The inconsistent results in comments on [Why is MAP_GROWSDOWN mapping does not grow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56888725/why-is-map-growsdown-mapping-does-not-grow) (some people finding it works, some finding it still segfaults when touching the return value and the page below) sound like https://bugs.centos.org/view.php?id=4767 - `MAP_GROWSDOWN` may even be buggy outside of the way the standard main-stack `VM_GROWSDOWN` mapping is used.

Comment: If we examine the source code of `pmap`, we can see that it [relies](https://gitlab.com/procps-ng/procps/blob/master/proc/readproc.c#L591) on information from the /proc/pid/stat file to determine whether a given address is in a stack or not. An object of type `proc_t` with this information is initialized [here](https://gitlab.com/procps-ng/procps/blob/master/pmap.c#L1169). One of the fields is `start_stack`, which holds the base address of program stack (the stack of the main thread). `pmap` also [uses](https://gitlab.com/procps-ng/procps/blob/master/pmap.c#L541)...

Comment: ...`/proc/pid/smap` to get the size of the stack. Then at [this](https://gitlab.com/procps-ng/procps/blob/master/pmap.c#L232) line of code, it compares a given address to the base stack address, and, if it falls in the stack region, it is marked as `[ stack ]`. Therefore, it doesn't matter whether a memory region is allocated using the `MAP_GROWSDOWN` flag or not. The tool just doesn't check this flag. In addition, when passing the `MAP_GROWSDOWN` flag to `mmap`, it gets translated to an internal flag called `VM_GROWSDOWN`...

Comment: It is this flag that is checked by the page fault handler to determine whether a page fault has occurred in a stack and that it should grow the stack (if possible). All threads' stacks are marked with `VM_GROWSDOWN`. I think that had `pmap` used `MAP_GROWSDOWN` instead of comparing with program stack address, it would have printed `[ stack ]` for any region allocated with this flag, even if the region is not used as a thread's stack.

Comment: So the `mmap(2)` man page is accurate when it says that `MAP_GROWSDOWN` is "used for stacks," because it is.

Comment: @HadiBrais: Are you sure `pthread_create` actually does use `MAP_GROWSDOWN` for allocating this region for thread stacks, though?  From what I've read it doesn't do that, but I don't have time to double-check right now.

Comment: `pthread_create` doesn't use that flag (see the mmap [call](https://github.molgen.mpg.de/git-mirror/glibc/blob/20003c49884422da7ffbc459cdeee768a6fee07b/nptl/allocatestack.c#L511) to allocate the stack). Only the stack of the main thread is created with that flag. But then I'm not sure how the page fault handler can tell whether an address belongs to a stack region in that case. BTW, all memory regions allocated with that flag are marked with a flag called `gd` (stands for grows down) in `cat /proc/pid/smaps`. You can easily tell using `smaps`.

Comment: @HadiBrais: thread stacks don't grow, they're fully allocated with `ulimit -s` space.  Only normal mmap lazy-allocation mechanisms avoid wasting physical pages and page-table space on them.

Comment: I made some edits if don't mind. You may also want to remove or edit the sentence that says "laughably out of date."

Comment: @HadiBrais: Why wouldn't I say "laughably out of date"?  glibc maintainers (specifically Drepper) were explaining how broken `MAP_GROWSDOWN` was back in 2008 (https://lwn.net/Articles/294001/), and proposing deprecating then removing it from the Linux kernel and/or glibc.  If you're thinking about the connection with in-kernel `VM_GROWSDOWN` for the main stack, remember that I'm talking specifically about the flag for the user-space `mmap` system call there, which isn't involved at all in setting up that mapping.

Comment: Fair point. Is there any further discussion on that from other kernel developers? I found only one response to Drepper [here](http://lkml.iu.edu/hypermail/linux/kernel/0808.1/2987.html), which disagrees with removing `MAP_GROWSDOWN`.

Comment: @HadiBrais: Just finished an update to my answer.  Thanks for the edit, that discussion of in-kernel VM flags was useful.  I put back in the fact(?) that nothing in user-space normally uses `MAP_GROWSDOWN` because I think that's an important point.  I didn't look for any further discussion, but yes clearly `MAP_GROWSDOWN` didn't actually get removed from glibc headers.